# Position buttons in container as a grid using CSS

Tags: html, css, grid

I have a container with multiple anchor tags styled as buttons (it could have more or less buttons):

```
<div class="menu-container">
    <div class="button-container">
       <a href="#/Action1" class="button">Action1</a>
       <a href="#/Action2" class="button">Action2</a>
       <a href="#/Action3" class="button">Action3</a>
       <a href="#/Action4" class="button">Action4</a>
       <a href="#/Action5" class="button">Action5</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

How ca I style this using CSS to be able to have those buttons listed as a grid with 4 columns max? I tried with `display:inline-block` and `float:left` but without success.

I know that I need to fix a width for the container but I'm not able to but all anchor tags inside the container. And this must be dinamic as is could have more or less buttons...

What I'm trying to achieve is something like:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to give the links a `width` and `height` in addition to `float` or `inline`.  Also, you need to define a width for the parent element, so that you can define where they can 'float' to.

```
.button-container {
    width: 520px;
    background: gray;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

.button-container > a {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    float: left;
    background: lightgray;   
    margin: 15px;
}
```

Here is an [implementation with jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ncq3Q/)

Next time try to include an example with fiddle so we can understand what you have already tried and where the code could have gone wrong.

Comment: Thanks, it worked! I will do it next time ;) Can you help me with one more thing? I edited th jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ncq3Q/1/. Now, I would like to make the text expand in multiple line if necessary. can I do it with anchor tags?

Comment: From what the code looks like, you are using the text-height to vertically center the text.  If you want it to expand to multiple lines, you need to find another solution to vertically align the content

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you are looking for. http://jsfiddle.net/H9Ypc/
I added a `div` with the css properties

`.action-container{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}`

Definitely suggest inline-block over float.

Comment: If you're going to suggest inline block over float, you should take a little time to make your jsfiddle demo look a little nicer so that it's convincing. I totally understand it on the technical grounds, but the other answer has a much nicer-looking demo.